# Spring Security LDAP Authentication and gather user details from local database

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

In summary, user is being authenticated, but I do appear to actually have logged into the users account.

I'm currently working on implementing LDAP authentication on a project. It appears that the authentication portion of things are working in the sense that my application does accept the correct credentials. The issue I'm having is that I cant seem to access 'principal' in my jsp views. (I was able to access all of this before making the switch to LDAP). When running a trace my CustomUserDetails service is querying and pulling the correct account information. Any assistance is appreciated

This will display the proper username:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   <h2><sec:authentication property="name"/></h2>
</sec:authorize>
```

This does not (it did work before LDAP)

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   <h2><sec:authentication property="principal.firstName"/></h2>
</sec:authorize>
```

Relevant Code
SecurityConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public CustomSaltSource customSaltSource(){ return new CustomSaltSource();}

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }



    @Autowired
    void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource()
                .url("ldap://bar.foo.com")
                .port(####)
                .and()
                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},cn=users,dc=ms,dc=ds,dc=foo,dc=com")
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(new UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(userDetailsService));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/skins/**", "/css/**", "/**/laggingComponents", "/assets/**").permitAll().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").anonymous()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().rememberMe().key("KEY").userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluator());
        web.expressionHandler(handler);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/skins/**", "/css/**", "/api/**", "/assets/**", "/health"); //"/**/test/**"
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetaulsService.java

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
        Session session = DBFactory.factory.openSession();
        User user = (User) session.createQuery("from User where userName =:userName")
                .setParameter("userName", username).uniqueResult();
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found");
        }
        //Needed to initialize permissions
        Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        int i = roles.size();
        for(Role role: roles){
            int j = role.getPermissions().size();
        }
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user);

        session.close();
        return userDetails;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm not wrong,
You switched to Ldap Authorization, set url and DN patterns but still provide userDetailsService which search user in database.
You need to set *UserDetailsContextMapper* by implementing the interface and creating your custom one. This will map data from ldap directory context to your custom *UserDetails* and return it through *mapUserFromContext* method.

Here is an example *CustomUserDetailsContextMapper*:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {


    private LdapUser ldapUser = null;
    private String commonName;

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();
        UserDetails ldapUserDetails = (UserDetails) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities);
        try {
            commonName = attributes.get("cn").get().toString();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ldapUser = new LdapUser(ldapUserDetails);
        ldapUser.setCommonName(commonName);
        return ldapUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {

    }
}
```

My custom *LdapUser*:

```
public class LdapUser implements UserDetails
{
    private String commonName;
    private UserDetails ldapUserDetails;

    public LdapUser(LdapUserDetails ldapUserDetails) {
        this.ldapUserDetails = ldapUserDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDn() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getDn();
    }

    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {

    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isAccountNonExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isAccountNonLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isEnabled();
    }
}
```

Then set CustomUserDetailsContextMapper in auth configuration. This is how you will be able to get your user from *authentication.getPrincipal()*.
I hope I correctly understand your problem and answered.

Comment: You probably meant `extends LdapUserDetailsMapper` instead of `implements UserDetailsContextMapper` to call `super` and enrich `LdapUser`

Answer (score 3):

I had to test LDAP auth + different roles for devs,admins,users

Many thanks to @Yernar Arystanov

The code is not so clean but works...

```
public class LdapUser implements UserDetails
{
    private String commonName;
    private List<String>  groups;
    private UserDetails ldapUserDetails;

    public LdapUser(LdapUserDetails ldapUserDetails) {
        this.ldapUserDetails = ldapUserDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return ldapUserDetails.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isAccountNonExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isAccountNonLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return ldapUserDetails.isEnabled();
    }

    public String getCommonName() {
        return commonName;
    }

    public void setCommonName(String commonName) {
        this.commonName = commonName;
    }

    public List<String> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<String> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

Suggestion by @Ivan Baranuk was correct (extends LdapUserDetailsMapper):

```
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

    private LdapUser ldapUser = null;
    private String commonName;
    private List<String> groups = new LinkedList<String>();

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();
        UserDetails ldapUserDetails;
        ldapUserDetails = (UserDetails) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities);
        try {
            commonName = attributes.get("cn").get().toString();

            Arrays.stream(ctx.getObjectAttributes("memberOf"))
                    .iterator()
                    .forEachRemaining( m -> {
                        groups.add(m.toString());
                    });

        } catch (NamingException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ldapUser = new LdapUser((LdapUserDetails) ldapUserDetails);
        ldapUser.setCommonName(commonName);
        ldapUser.setGroups(groups);
        return ldapUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {

    }
}
```

then finally in SecurityConfig:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
...
auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("enter your search base")
                .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))")
                .userDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsMapper())
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator())
                .contextSource()
                .url(yourProperties.getLdapUrl())
                .managerDn(yourProperties.getManagerDn())
                .managerPassword(yourProperties.getManagerPassword());
}

private LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator() {
        return new LdapAuthoritiesPopulator() {
            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData,
                                                                                String username) {

                LinkedList<SimpleGrantedAuthority> res = new LinkedList();
                Arrays.stream(userData.getObjectAttributes("memberOf"))
                        .iterator()
                        .forEachRemaining( m -> {
                            if(m.toString().equals("your_dev_group"))
                                res.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("DEV_USER"));
                            if(m.toString().equals("your_admin_group"))
                                res.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN_USER"));
                        });
                if(res.isEmpty())
                    return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
                else
                    return res;
            }
        };
    }
@Bean
@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return super.userDetailsService();
}

@Bean
    protected LdapUserDetailsMapper ldapUserDetailsMapper() {return new CustomUserDetailsContextMapper();}

}
```

At the end - some simple get method(authorized users only):

```
@RequestMapping("/logger")
public String testLogger(Authentication authentication) {
    if (authentication.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_DEV_USER"))) {
        LdapUser userDetails = (LdapUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        log.info("WELCOME :" + userDetails.getCommonName());
        userDetails.getGroups().iterator().forEachRemaining((g) - > log.info("group: " + g.toString()));
    }
    return ""
}
```